# If the vectors $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}-{b}$ are linearly dependent, show that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are collinear

Tags: geometry, vectors

> If the vectors $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}-{b}$ are linearly dependent, show that $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are collinear.

From the linear dependence $$k\left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)+m\left(\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right)=\vec{0}$$ I didn't quite get if $k$ and $m$ can be equal to $0$. Or maybe just one of them? To be completely honest the theory in my book is explained in the worst possible way.
$$k\left(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right)=-m\left(\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right)\\\vec{a}+\vec{b}=-\dfrac{m}{k}\left(\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right), k\ne 0$$ From here we can conclude that $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}-\vec{b}$ are collinear, right? What can we do next? Thank you!

P.S. If two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{t}$ are linearly dependent, are they always collinear? That's what I actually got.

Comment: $$k(a+b)+m(a-b)=\frac{k+m}2\cdot\vec a+\frac{k-m}2\cdot\vec b=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\vec a+\vec b$ and $\vec a-\vec b$ are linearly dependent, then ne of them is the other one times a scalar. If $\vec a+\vec b=\lambda\left(\vec a-\vec b\right)$, then $(1-\lambda)\vec a=(-1-\lambda)\vec b$ and so, since the numbers $1-\lambda$ and $-1-\lambda$ cannot both be equal to $0$, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are collinear.

If $\vec a-\vec b=\lambda\left(\vec a+\vec b\right)$, the argument is similar.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I got the idea, appreciate you! "If $\vec{a}+\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a}-\vec{b}$ are linearly dependent, then one of them is the other one times a scalar". Isn't this the same as if the vectors were collinear? If so, what's the difference?

Comment: Also may I ask you what happens if e.g. the numbers $1-\lambda$ and $-1-\lambda$ can both be equal to $0$? I mean if we could get the situation $0\vec{a}=0\vec{b}$.

Comment: Yes, you have have two vectors, they are collinear if and only if they are linearly dependent. And if $1-\lambda=-1-\lambda=0$, then $\lambda$ is equal to both $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: You meant two, right? What if they are more than 2?

Comment: Yes, I meant two (and I've edited my comment). And, in $\Bbb R^2$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$ are linearly dependent. However, they are not collinear.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what $R^2$ and the other numbers in brackets mean. Can you clarify it for me?

Comment: The set $\Bbb R^2$ is the Cartesian product $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. Its elements are pairs of the form $(a,b)$, with $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Continuing my work, $$k\vec{a}+k\vec{b}=-m\vec{a}+m\vec{b}\\(k+m)\vec{a}=(m-k)\vec{b}$$ I don't get what's happening now and why are we checking if $k+m$ and $m-k$ can be equal to zero.

Comment: If at least one of them is not $0$, then $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are linearly dependent, and therefore collinear. And they cannot be both equal to $0$; since it would follow from that that $k=m=0$.